# How can I use my existing array like a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

I have an array which hold controls my UI inventory list. When I add a `GameObject` to the array, the function also adds the same `GameObject` to my inventory UI.

In my script I also have a remove function that removes the `GameObject` from the array and removes the `GameObject` from the UI.

My issue is that I need to change this array to a list so that it can work dynamically, as a list has built in functionality to move the the elements of the array to the front of the array (that is move them left in the array index).

For example, currently when using an array, when I choose items 1,2,3,4, and 5. I then proceed to remove item 3. What is left in my array is 1,2,null,4, and 5. As well, what is left in my inventory UI are `GameObject`s in slots 1,2,null,4,5. The null in this case is a UI image with nothing on it.

By converting this array to a list I believe I can avoid having gaps in the inventory UI. As well, I know my array and or list will always be 16 items.

I have tried converting the existing array to a list and using all methods that correspond to the list methods.

The original array usage:

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] inventory = new GameObject[16];
    public List<GameObject> inventory2 = new List<GameObject>();

    public void AddItem(GameObject item)
    {
        bool itemAdded = false;

        //find the first open slot in inventory
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i] == null)
            {
                inventory[i] = item;

                //Update UI
                InventoryButtons[i].image.overrideSprite = 
    item.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

My attempt to convert this to a list and use it as such:

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> inventory = new List<GameObject>();

    public void AddItem(GameObject item)
    {
        bool itemAdded = false;

        //find the first open slot in inventory
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i] == null)
            {
                inventory[i] = item;

                //Update UI
                InventoryButtons[i].image.overrideSprite = 
     item.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I thought lists and arrays work the same, I thought my method would work, but the list is still acting as an array, that is, it is not dynamically moving items in the array to the front after items have been deleted from the array.

Comment: Minor tip with code blocks on SO: they must have one blank line between the start of the code and the previous line of paragraph text. The double ` is not necessary, but you can surround text with single back ticks to refer to short words of inline code like this: "I get an error on the line `var v = nullthing.Property` - why is that"

Comment: First, when you post a question to Stack Overflow, you really need to include a good [mcve]. See also [ask] for additional tips. Second, while `List<T>` does provide dynamic sizing, insertion, and deletion, you have to actually use those features. Nothing in your code example shows how you are removing items from the list, but based on what you did post and your description, it's a likely bet that you didn't really change the code, but just changed the data type. If so, then of course the list will work just like the array. Use the `List<T>.RemoveAt()` method instead, and `Add()` for adding.

Comment: Also, there's no need to include information in the post itself explaining edits. That's why there's a revision history for every post, and a comment for every edit.

Comment: *"As well, I know my array and or list will always be 16 items."* If you use a `List<T>` and properly use `RemoveAt` your list will then have `Count-1` items. There will *be no gap* for you to search for. Your `for` loop will stop iterating at the new `Count`, never touching the "gap" indices at the end (they don't exist!). You'll need `Add` to put things at the end of the list. But overall your number of items will fluctuate, as will the number of slots you can index into (the underlying array may never be resized passed the original length of 16, but that's an implementation detail)

Answer (score 0):

If the array version works out and you always want 16 items why not just do this to remove an item:

```
//remove item at index 5
for (int i = 5; i < inventory.Count - 1; i++)
  inventory[i] = inventory[i+1];

inventory[inventory.Length - 1] = null;
```

We start at index 5, the one to be removed, and proceed to the end of the array-1 copying each next item over the top of the current one. Then we finish the loop and make the last item null